# Visualizing TimeSeries with Bokeh - datapoints overlap

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a value for each point in time (updated each half an hour).

I read the data from csv into a pandas dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
headers = ['timestamp', 'pressure']
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, names=headers)
```

The data types are:

```
timestamp    object
pressure      int64
```

The df itself looks like this:

```
             timestamp  pressure
0  2016-01-29 10:00:00         3
1  2016-01-30 22:30:00         2
2  2016-01-31 04:30:00         1
```

I visualize it like following:

```
fig = TimeSeries(df, x = 'timestamp', y = 'pressure',builder_type='point'
                                                    ,xscale="datetime")
```

And what it returns is:

[image]

However, if i remove the time part - it will work fine:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting webgl=False.

There was an [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3137) in webgl in Bokeh 0.10 causing jumping datapoints when the plot was zoomed in. It had to do with round-off errors with the rendering. I suspect that the current behaviour is related to this, and that problems are not quite sorted out.

Try this minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

no_of_datapoints=10

base = datetime(2016, 2, 1, 9, 36, 0)
date_list = [base - timedelta(minutes=x) for x in range(0, no_of_datapoints)]
datapoints=np.arange(no_of_datapoints)

p=bk.figure(webgl=True,x_axis_type="datetime")
p.scatter(x=date_list,y=datapoints)
bk.show(p)
```

Setting webgl=True gives the diagram:
[image: incorrect diagram when webgl=True]

webgl=False gives the diagram:
[image: correct diagram when webgl=False]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems to work well. I've decided to switch to pure D3.js though :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help! The behaviour has been confirmed as a [bug by the Bokeh team](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3795) and is marked as an action for the 0.12 release.